# Recursion - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method as follows, but I am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax, I wonder what I am doing wrong

> Given a non-negative integer num, repeatedly add all its digits until
>   the result has only one digit.
>
> For example:
>
> Given num = 38, the process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2
>   has only one digit, return it.

```
class Solution(object):
    def addDigits(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        return self.addDigits(x=sum(i for i in str(num)) if x%9<10:
```

**Note:** 
I am learning recursion in python, therefore rather than knowing how to solve problem, I would love to learn what I am doing wrong in my implementation.

Comment: So what's the code supposed to do when x >= 10? If you want help fixing code, you have to explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: what are you passing to num as? it looks like maybe a string and you want to add the digits?

Comment: Your argument is `num` but you're passing `x` as the kwarg?

Comment: Yeah, that *is* invalid syntax, and I can't even guess what it's supposed to do…

Comment: @Aran-Fey Question is updated

Comment: oh are you trying to add the digits of an int by casting it to a string and recursively adding?

Comment: By the way, that's _really_ not how classes and methods are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to match the new question description:

```
def add_digits(x):
    return (x - 1) % 9 + 1 if x else 0
```

If you apply the brute force version of this solution (the one you were originally attempting) then you will see the output is actually the sequence listed here: https://oeis.org/A010888.

Once we know that this is a repeating sequence we can look for patterns in the sequence, and in this case we realize that the function in this answer provides a guaranteed solution in O(1) time and space.

You can actually see the relationship to  `n % 9` by seeing this sequence here: https://oeis.org/A010878

Comment: I am learning recursion method, therefore rather than knowing how to solve problem, I would love to learn what I am doing wrong in my implementation. I have upvoted your effort.

Comment: @GrantWilliams your answer only adds the digits up, but does not produce the desired single digit outcome the OP was asking for (i.e. returns 11 for 38 instead of 2)

Comment: @MihaiChelaru You are correct. When i originally wrote the answer, the question was quite a bit more ambiguous

Comment: @hotspring you actually don't need recursion (or iteration) to solve this problem. If you are just learning about recursion i'd really recommend looking into something like the Fibonacci sequence or a factorial program. It's a lot easier to wrap your head around.

Comment: why are you subtracting 1 referring to `(x-1)` from the number then applying modulo  referring to `(x-1) % 9` operation and then adding 1 `(x-1) % 9  + 1`  to the number? could you please explain your logic?

Comment: why are you subtracting 1 referring to `(x-1)` before applying modulos?

Comment: The sequence is called the additive digital root of n `seq 888`. You can read more about it if you like, or you can see that the sequence of `n % 9` i.e. `seq 878` (ignoring the base case of 0) is the same except that `seq878` is 0-8 instead of 1-9 like `seq888` is. We can use this new sequence, `seq878`, and adjust our current value to fit it by subtracting 1 from x and then doing modulo 9 (making it part of `seq878` then adding 1 back to it to convert back to `seq888`.